# Autocomplete navigator chrome firefox edge

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge

I have a form and there are two fields that chrome autocompletes. These fields are the email and the password.

I don't want it to autocomplete, and I've tried this:

```
autocomplete="off"
```

This works for fields that are of type text, like name. This one with that characteristic no longer reminds me.
But the password even with that keeps reminding me.

I have investigated changing the name and the ID and nothing keeps reminding me.

Until I have removed the typo and put text on it. Now it doesn't remind me or autocomplete it. But of course I can't let users enter passwords and see them.

I have tried with js to put the type text and when the user clicks on it (onFucus) it will change it to type password. But of course when the user clicks, I get a password type and now the browsers remind me of the passwords again.

My question is this:
I can put this text type input but every time the user writes, asterisks appear.

Comment: Does same issue occurs in Microsoft Edge? If  this is the case, have you tried to disabled the feature `Save and fill basic info` under the path `edge://settings/personalinfo`?

Comment: The problem will be the rest of the users who do not do this process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, to solve this problem, I changed the input type to text. With that it no longer tells me the passwords.
But how to solve the problem that passwords are seen?
Very simple, a font has been created that is all circles imitating passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Set autocomplete to false in your form's opening tag -> `<form autocomplete="false">`. False works cross-browser, and you can see an explanation as to why here: [Autocomplete off vs false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053167/autocomplete-off-vs-false)

Comment: Thank you but with the version of Chrome that I am using it does not work for me. Not with Edge. Not with Firefox.

Comment: Some browsers ignore autocomplete attributes if the inputs don't have names. See this for more: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35448269/angular-materials-can-you-disable-the-autocomplete-suggestions-for-an-input/60335213#60335213).

Comment: I have put as name "rtyytryrt". But the problem is that it detects that it is a password type and that is when it remembers me.